# Trouble when using QNetworkReply in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm new in C++ also with QT, my current QT version is 5.5.1.
I have an issue when using connect with QNetworkReply and QNetworkAccessManager. When I try to assign a variable from another file to data fetched from API, it always calls the function first before connecting to the API so that the variable is always empty. Can you guys help me?

```
void NioshFunc::fetchDataFromAPI(){
        QUrl url;
        QUrlQuery querystr;
        querystr.addQueryItem("$format","json");
        url.setScheme("https");
        url.setHost("example.com");
        url.setPath("/aaaa/dataset");
        url.setQuery(querystr);
        QNetworkRequest request;
        request.setUrl(url);
        request.setRawHeader("KeyId", "xxx-xxx-xxx");
        reply = manager->get(request);
        connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::readyRead, this, &NioshFunc::readyRead);
        connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &NioshFunc::finished);
}
```

```
void NioshFunc::readyRead(){
    dataBuffer.append(reply->readAll());
}
```

```
void NioshFunc::finished(){
    if(reply->error())
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR!";
        qDebug() << reply->errorString();
        qDebug() << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
        qDebug() << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpReasonPhraseAttribute).toString();
    }else{

        qDebug() << "SUCCESS";
        qDebug() << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
        qDebug() << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpReasonPhraseAttribute).toString();
        nioshWPDataFromAPI = QJsonDocument::fromJson(dataBuffer);
        qDebug() << nioshWPDataFromAPI;
        dataBuffer.clear();
    }
    reply->deleteLater();

}
```

```
bool NioshFunc::parse(){
  Globals *g = Globals::getHandle();
  if (nioshWPDataFromAPI.isEmpty() || nioshWPDataFromAPI.isNull()) return false;
    QVariantMap root = nioshWPDataFromAPI.toVariant().toMap();
    if (root.isEmpty()) return false;
    QVariantMap d = root["d"].toMap();
    if (d.isEmpty()) return false;
    QVariantList results = d["results"].toList();
    if (results.isEmpty()) return false;
    foreach (QVariant varResult, results)
    {
        QVariantMap result = varResult.toMap();
        if (result.isEmpty()) return false;
        g->struct_tableColumn.input.duration = result["Duration"].toString();
        g->struct_tableColumn.input.id = result["Id"].toString();
        if (id.isEmpty() || id.isNull()) return false;
        g->struct_tableColumn.input.load_cumul_Limit = result["LoadCumulLimit"].toString();
        g->struct_tableColumn.input.Notes = result["Notes"].toString();
        qDebug() << g->struct_tableColumn.input.id << g->struct_tableColumn.input.duration << g->struct_tableColumn.input.load_cumul_Limit << g->struct_tableColumn.input.Notes; // "it is empty for all variable from globals file.
    }
    return true;

}
```

When I can function fetchDataFromAPI() and call function parse() in another file named globals, that is always called 2 these functions first before connecting to API, so that the variable named "nioshWPDataFromAPI" is always empty. But when I read nioshWPDataFromAPI in function finished(), it still has data, but only in function finished(). Could you guys help me? Sorry if my question is not too clear for you guys

Comment: Hi Me3nTaL, How can I do that? Could you help explain it in more detail pls

Comment: When I move connect(...) to before calling reply = manager->get(request). I have an error is "QObject::connect: invalid null parameter". Do you know the root cause ? Thank you

Comment: @Me3nTaL Re.`"You have to connect the signals before you execute the request by calling get()"`: no, that's not correct.  Please see the examples in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details).  The only condition is that `connect` be called before handing control back to the event loop.

Comment: @G.M. I guess that I did the right thing when using connect in my codebase right? So could you help me with the main problem?

Comment: Run your code under a debugger to follow its execution.  Is `NioshFunc::readyRead` called when expected?  In `NioshFunc::finished` do the contents of `dataBuffer` look correct?  Does `QJsonDocument::fromJson(dataBuffer)` succeed (you can pass `QJsonDocument::fromJson` a pointer to a [`QJsonParseError`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qjsonparseerror.html) that will provide diagnostic info)?

Comment: with my code above. When I call the function `fetchDataFromAPI` in file globals, the function `fetchDataFromAPI` will be called first before 2 functions `readyRead` and `finished`, so that in the function finished when I parse data to the global variable then it just effects only `finished()` function, not in the `fetchDataFromAPI()` function